# mark current year with boxobj (zedGraph and C#)

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I need some graphs which show me the development of our customers.
Because the data from the current year is still changing, I'd like too 'highlight' the region of the current year.

Because pictures are better than 1.000 words:

This is my current graph:
[image]

and it should look like this:
[image]

*(I know that 2012 is not the current year, these are just some sample datas ;))*

Unfortunately the zedGraphs boxObj is really bugging me an I can't get it to work in any way.

This is my graphs code so far:

```
        graphControl.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();

        graphControl.GraphPane.Title.Text = "Umsatz-Jahresvergleich von " + kunde.Name;
        graphControl.GraphPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Jahr";
        graphControl.GraphPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Umsatz in €";

        ArrayList arrYears          = new ArrayList();
        List<String> lstYearStrings = new List<string>();
        double[] xValue2 = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        ArrayList arrActYear = new ArrayList();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Jahresumsatz> kvp in kunde.Umsaetze.OrderBy(key => key.Key))
        {
            arrYears.Add(kvp.Value.UmsatzNetto);
            lstYearStrings.Add(kvp.Value.Jahr.ToString());
        }

        graphControl.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = lstYearStrings.ToArray();
        graphControl.GraphPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text;
        graphControl.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.FontSpec.Angle = 90;

        LineItem curve = graphControl.GraphPane.AddCurve("Umsatz im Jahresvergleich", xValue2, (double[])arrYears.ToArray(typeof(double)), Color.Red, SymbolType.Circle);
        curve.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(160, 230, 145, 205), 90F);
        curve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Red);


        /* One of my many experiments with BoxObj... it's not working of cause :(
        BoxObj box = new BoxObj(0.5, 0.5, 40, 40, Color.Empty,Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightGreen));
        box.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(200, Color.LightGreen), 45.0F);
        box.ZOrder = ZOrder.E_BehindCurves;
        box.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
        box.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;*/

        graphControl.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(box);

        graphControl.GraphPane.AxisChange();

        graphControl.Refresh();
```

It would be really cool if someone could help me with this one.

By the way, the BoxObj needs to be dynamic in some way, so that is scales with the graph and still fits if the chosen years vary.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I tried something below along the lines of what you have and see the transparent green rectangle :

```
BoxObj box = new BoxObj(3, 70, 1, 70, Color.Empty,Color.FromArgb(100, Color.LightGreen));
box.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(120, Color.LightGreen), 45.0F);
box.ZOrder = ZOrder.A_InFront;
box.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
box.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It is still not working as expected, but you pointed me in the right direction ;)